# Debug Code in Python

Tags: python, arrays, debugging

I have to debug code, however I don't see what's wrong with it. I didn't write it and usually struggle debugging code I didn't write. I tried tinkering with it, however it keeps saying x is undefined. Thank you

instructions:
Fix the function that has an integer array input, from that we must determine the biggest number out of all the x elements in the array, then we must return the biggest number within that array

code:

```
def findLargestNum(nums):
    temp = 10000
    nums_size = len(nums)
    for i in range(0, nums_size):
        if nums[x] > temp:
            temp = nums[x]
return temp
```

Comment: Well did you define `x`? Maybe you meant `i`?

Comment: looks like it should be nums[x]

Comment: The message `x is undefined` usually occurs because you did not define the variable `x`. Variables are typically defined using assignment, e.g. `x = something`. You do not have any assignment statements with x on the left hand side. They can also be defined by being in the argument list of a function call, or being the iterating variable in a for loop. You do not have `x` in either of those places.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are a few things with this code.

First, what the debug is saying:

It says the variable X, has no meaning / is not defined anywhere

How to fix this:

replace every mention of X with i

So your code should look like this:

```
def findLargestNum(nums):
    temp = 10000
    nums_size = len(nums)
    for i in range(0, nums_size):
        if nums[i] > temp:
            temp = nums[i]
return temp
```

Third, to make this code more efficient:

If your task is to find the largest number in an array, python has at least 2 separate functions to do this. Either of the following two count replace the entire code:

```
max(nums)
np.max(nums)
```

the np.max function assumes you imported numpy as np. Aside from both being much easier to read, they will be significantly faster (np.max is especially optimized to work on large arrays)